# How to do collation sorting with lowercase first?

Tags: sorting, collation, icu, icu4j, custom-sort

***Input***

For the given list of below strings,

```
Senthil
Anbu
arthi
Sugumar
suresh
venila
```

***Expected***

I want the sorting order to be

```
arthi
Anbu
suresh
Senthil
Sugumar
venila
```

***Actual***

But getting the follow order

```
Anbu
arthi
Senthil
Sugumar
suresh
venila
```

I tried the following option

```
strength primary
caseLevel off
caseFirst lower
```

How to tailor the rules, so that i can get the desired sort order?

Thanks in advance. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append rules:

> &a<A<b<B<c<C<d<D<e<E<f<F<g<G<h<H<i<I<j<J<k<K<l<L<m<M<n<N<o<O<p<P<q<Q<r<R<s<S<t<T<u<U<v<V<w<W<x<X<y<Y<z<Z

It works. But there is probably a more elegant solution.